# Android - Emulator takes a long time to start up

Tags: boot, memory, android, emulator

I have successfully installed Android-SDK in my computer. Generally, I test application with my real android Device (HTC HERO) so it is fast to test an application on a real device.

But when I try to run the emulator with an already created AVD, it takes lot of time to load an emulator , I have already seen some articles and discussion boards where people are throwing the same questions regarding the same problem.

So please, what I have to do so that emulator loads up fast every time?

My PC has 2GB of RAM, and I think its sufficient for what I need it to do. So I believe its not due to a lack of memory.

Comment: I have the same problem, so I agree this issue is with the emulator itself and not necessarily your hardware or configuration.  Will monitor this post for useful answers.

Comment: Usual solution is to leave the simulator running, and just deploy latest code versions to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To maximize the accuracy between emulator and real devices, Google emulator uses ARM opcode, a kind of machine language. It must convert from ARM opcode to Intel opcode. That's why it's slow. My computer is 3GB RAM but it's still slow and lagged. The problem seems not to be RAM but CPU. Improving CPU will improve the emulator.

To use emulator more effectively, this is my experience:

- Don't close emulator everytime you run your application.
- Scale the emulator screen smaller.
- Disable snapshot (Yes, it's useful but it takes time to close the
  emulator).
- Specify a file path for SD card image file. I use only one SD card
  for many AVDs.
- If you got any problems in adb, just reset adb, don't close emulator.
- Open few programs in your operating sytem.
- If you are using Windows, don't ever close emulator. Do it combined
  with Hibernate of Windows.

References:

[Making the Android emulator run faster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662650/making-the-android-emulator-run-faster)

[Android emulator is very very slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6278962/android-emulator-is-very-very-slow) (My question)

Comment: +1 Awesome description and testing you have done and played with emulator :)

Answer (score 7):

The emulator is just slow, there is not much you can do about it.

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554099/slow-android-emulator

Comment: But there may be some reasons or bug or less feature, what u say !